# This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in cvector.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

I make many mistake in the test program!!!

debug src: http://www.cppblog.com/Files/mymsdn/cvector-windows-has-triggered-a-breakpoint-in-cvector.zip

the right version: http://www.cppblog.com/Files/mymsdn/cvector-svn-version-10.zip

I am trying to write a C language version of vector struction.

If I try run (in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, default short-cut is CTRL+F5) my code. It can execute as the right logical to output right result.

But If I try run it in debug mode(in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, default short-cut is F5). It will cause a problem: (it's from the output window, and also has a alert frame to report it)

> HEAP[cvector.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 393168 modified at 393190 after it was freed
>   Windows has triggered a breakpoint in cvector.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in cvector.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while cvector.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [cppblog.com](http://www.cppblog.com/images/cppblog_com/mymsdn/3630/o_windows-has-triggered-a-breakpoint-in-cvector.png))</sub>

Comment: You will need to provide us some example code or some more information if we're going to help you.

Comment: Probably you are using a pointer after freeing it. You should post your code to allow us to see where the problem may be.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5035063/908336

Answer (score 4):

This error means you have written to a memory address that you did not actually "own" — eg, you wrote to memory after it had been freed, or outside the region you had actually allocated with `new` or `malloc`, or through a pointer that was just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check your debug settings.  Turn off "unmanaged code debugging" and "SQL Server debugging."

That worked for me when I was getting this with Oracle components.  If I kept hitting Continue, there was no break error and the program kept going.  Turning off those debug options let it keep going and the program works now.

Comment: That didn't make the bug go away, it just hid it under the rug! All you did was turn off the feature in the debugger that warns you when you've corrupted your heap -- the corruption is still there, waiting like a landmine to explode the next time some other code tries to use that region of heap.