# This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in testcrypto.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

class PasswordCrypt
{
public:
    PasswordCrypt(std::vector<uint8_t> buffer);
    ~PasswordCrypt(void);
    void PassCrypto(std::vector<uint8_t> buffer);
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& Encrypt(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer);
    const std::vector<uint8_t>& Decrypt(std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer);
private:
    uint8_t* key;
};

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "PasswordCrypt.h"

PasswordCrypt::PasswordCrypt(std::vector<uint8_t> buffer)
{
    this->key = new uint8_t[200];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i< buffer.size() ;i++)
        sum += buffer[i];
    srand(sum);
    uint8_t hash[0x10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x10; i++)
    hash[i] =(uint8_t)rand();
    for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
        {
            key[i * 2] = (uint8_t)i;
            key[(i * 2) + 1] = (uint8_t)(i ^ hash[i & 0x0F]);
        }
    for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
    for (int j = 1 + i; j < 0x100; j++)
        if (key[(i * 2) + 1] < key[(j * 2) + 1])
        {
            key[i * 2] ^= key[j * 2];
            key[j * 2] ^= key[i * 2];
            key[i * 2] ^= key[j * 2];
            key[(i * 2) + 1] ^= key[(j * 2) + 1];
            key[(j * 2) + 1] ^= key[(i * 2) + 1];
            key[(i * 2) + 1] ^= key[(j * 2) + 1];
        }
}



PasswordCrypt::~PasswordCrypt(void)
{
    delete[] this->key;
}

const uint8_t scanCodeToVirtualKeyMap[] = 
{
    0x00, 0x1B, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0xBD, 0xBB, 0x08, 0x09,
    0x51, 0x57, 0x45, 0x52, 0x54, 0x59, 0x55, 0x49, 0x4F, 0x50, 0xDB, 0xDD, 0x0D, 0x11, 0x41, 0x53, 
    0x44, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0xBA, 0xC0, 0xDF, 0x10, 0xDE, 0x5A, 0x58, 0x43, 0x56, 
    0x42, 0x4E, 0x4D, 0xBC, 0xBE, 0xBF, 0x10, 0x6A, 0x12, 0x20, 0x14, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 
    0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x90, 0x91, 0x24, 0x26, 0x21, 0x6D, 0x25, 0x0C, 0x27, 0x6B, 0x23, 
    0x28, 0x22, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2C, 0x00, 0xDC, 0x7A, 0x7B, 0x0C, 0xEE, 0xF1, 0xEA, 0xF9, 0xF5, 0xF3, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFB, 0x2F, 0x7C, 0x7D, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0xED, 
    0x00, 0xE9, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xEB, 0x09, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x00,

};

const uint8_t virtualKeyToScanCodeMap[] =
{
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0x1C, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x2A, 0x1D, 0x38, 0x00, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x39, 0x49, 0x51, 0x4F, 0x47, 0x4B, 0x48, 0x4D, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x54, 0x52, 0x53, 0x63, 
    0x0B, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x20, 0x12, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x17, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x32, 0x31, 0x18, 
    0x19, 0x10, 0x13, 0x1F, 0x14, 0x16, 0x2F, 0x11, 0x2D, 0x15, 0x2C, 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x5D, 0x00, 0x5F, 
    0x52, 0x4F, 0x50, 0x51, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x37, 0x4E, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x53, 0x35, 
    0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x57, 0x58, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 
    0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x45, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x2A, 0x36, 0x1D, 0x1D, 0x38, 0x38, 0x6A, 0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x65, 0x66, 0x32, 0x20, 0x2E, 0x30, 
    0x19, 0x10, 0x24, 0x22, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6B, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x27, 0x0D, 0x33, 0x0C, 0x34, 0x35, 
    0x28, 0x73, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1A, 0x56, 0x1B, 0x2B, 0x29, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x71, 0x5C, 0x7B, 0x00, 0x6F, 0x5A, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x5B, 0x00, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x5E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D, 0x00, 0x62, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

};



const std::vector<uint8_t>& PasswordCrypt::Encrypt(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> result(buffer.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
    {
        bool upper = false;
        if (buffer[i] == 0) break;
        else
        {
            uint8_t b =this->key[buffer[i] * 2];
            if (b > 0x80) 
            {
                b = (uint8_t)(this->key[buffer[i] * 2] - 0x80);
                upper = true;
            }
            result[i] += scanCodeToVirtualKeyMap[b];
        }
        if (!upper && result[i] >= 'A' && result[i] <= 'Z') result[i] += 'a' - 'A';
    }

    return result;
}

const std::vector<uint8_t>& PasswordCrypt::Decrypt(std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> result(buffer.size(), 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j++)
    {
        uint8_t c = buffer[j];
        if (buffer[j] >= 'a' && buffer[j] <= 'z')
            buffer[j] -= 'a' - 'A';
        uint8_t d = virtualKeyToScanCodeMap[buffer[j]];
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            d += 0x80;
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            uint8_t b = (uint8_t)this->key[i * 2];
            if (b == d)
            {
                result[j] = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "PasswordCrypt.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


void output_hex(std::ostream& out, std::vector<uint8_t>& data) {
    for (std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator i=data.begin();i<data.end();i++)
        out << std::hex
            << std::setw(2)
            << std::setfill('0')
            << static_cast<int>(data[*i])
            << " ";
    out << endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string test="Hellow World!";
    std::vector<uint8_t> buf(test.begin(), test.end());
    PasswordCrypt dec(buf);
    //output_hex(cout, buf);
    std::vector<uint8_t> enced = dec.Encrypt(buf);
    //output_hex(cout, enced);
    std::vector<uint8_t> deced = dec.Decrypt(enced);
    //output_hex(cout, deced);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   testcrypto.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the
>   heap, which indicates a bug in
>   testcrypto.exe or any of the DLLs it
>   has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user
>   pressing F12 while testcrypto.exe has
>   focus.

Comment: Time to rummage around after the debugger, roll up your sleeves and do some debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a classic buffer overrun. Here you allocate 200 bytes for `key`:

```
this->key = new uint8_t[200];
```

Here, however:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 0x100; i++)
    {
        key[i * 2] = (uint8_t)i;
```

You (attempt to) write to `k[2]` through `key[2 * 0x100]`. 2 * 0x100 is 0x200, which is 512 in decimal. It would appear that where you allocate the buffer, you should really allocate `0x200` elements.

Some of the other code looks like it tries to access `key[0x200]` -- to make that work, you'd want/need to allocate 0x201 elements (0x200 elements will run from key[0] through key[0x1ff] inclusive).

Edit: doing a bit more looking, it gets even worse. Perhaps putting these three lines next to each other will make the next problem more obvious:

```
const std::vector<uint8_t>& PasswordCrypt::Encrypt(const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> result(buffer.size());

[ ...]

    return result;
```

You're returning a reference to a local variable, so the caller receives a dangling reference.

Comment: @MixedCoder: see edited answer pointing out yet another problem.

Comment: so what do u recommend me to change this codes to? since i was just trying to convert this method from C# to C++ so idk wats wrong so what do u think

Comment: Either modify have the caller pass a reference to a buffer that it modifies, or return the vector itself rather than a reference (I'd probably do the latter).

Answer (score 2):

```
j < 0x100;
```

0x100 is *not* the same as 100. It's 256. And your `key` array is only 200 elements long.

You then go off and try to access `key[j * 2]`, which is *way* off the end of the array, trampling all over random bits of memory. That's your problem.

Your other problem is using xor-swapping instead of something more readable - while you might think it's a "neat trick", it really isn't. It makes things much less legible and doesn't provide any meaningful performance benefit.